# Brownie Console Not Starting

Tags: brownie, console

I am trying to get the brownie console to start up.
In the command line, I am getting error when I type:

`brownie cosole`

The error message is shown in the screenshot. I have verified that brownie is properly installed by :

`brownie --version` as well as `brownie`

and i see the v1.15.1 is installed and all the commands list opens up fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have have ganache-cli installed. You need to install that first.

check by just typing `ganache-cli`

If not there, then install using npm:

`npm install -g ganache-cli`

Verify that you have npm installed using:

`npm -v`

If you do not have npm installed, you can download npm and nodejs using this link:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: No I did not have ganache-cli. I have the desktop app version of ganache. I did have npm and am trying to see after installing with ganache-cli.

Comment: you may also want to update your brownie version to 1.17